# Why does union not work with with statements?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

This will give an error:

```
with a1 as (select 2), a2 as (select 3)
a1 union a2;
-- ERROR:  syntax error at or near "a1"
```

But this will not:

```
(select 2) union (select 3);
/*
 ?column? 
----------
        2
        3
(2 rows)
*/
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Because your first query isn't formated properly and has some syntax errors, where is the `SELECT` statement? What is `a1 union a2` supposed to be?

This should work:

```
with a1 as (select 2), a2 as (select 3)
SELECT * FROM a1
UNION
SELECT * FROM a2;
```

This is usually used to make complicated calculation, and simplfy them. Not for `1 union 2`

This is basically creating derived table to use, after the `with` part, the query begin, so it should be formatted as a normal `select/update/delete` query, but `a1 & a2` will be available for use.